# Calculating average weight loss

Tags: sas

I have created a small data of weight loss

```
    ID      Name    Team    Before after Loss
1   1011    David   red     125    112   13 
2   1024    Alice   red     145    135   10 
3   1036    Alan    yellow  180    156   24 
4   1039    Ashley  red     145    130   15 
5   1019    Diana   yellow  128    109   19
```

How do I calculate the average loss as well as team wise average loss?

Comment: How do the "avg loss" and "team-wise avg loss" that you're asking for differ? Is "avg loss" supposed to be by id or name or something?

Comment: @superfluous, avg loss is the average weight loss. So in the case of the entire table, the average would be (13+10+24+15+19)/5 = 16.2. The team averages would be (13+10+15)/3 for red, and (24+19)/2 for yellow, resulting in 12.667 and 21.5 for yellow. I don't know SAS unfortunately, but I understand what he's trying to accomplish, so maybe you can help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as simple as:

```
proc sql;
/*average loss*/
select mean(loss) as avgLoss from table;
/*team average loss*/
select team, mean(loss) as avgLoss from table group by 1;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Proc means. This is the default output when using the class statement. The OP doesn't indicate if they want a table or report.

```
Proc means data=have;
Class team;
Var loss;
 Run;
```

This produces all base statistics at overall and team level. To get only the average, add the keyword mean to the proc statement.

```
 Proc means data=have mean;
```

Answer (score 0):

Proc summary works in much the same way as proc means...

```
proc summary data=table;
  class team;
  var loss;
  output out = summrydat
        mean = avgloss;
run;
```

In the output dataset, the first line (having `_TYPE_ = 0`) gives the total average, whereas subsequent lines (having `_TYPE_ = 1`) give grouped averages.